# requestLocation() in iOS 9 calls the didUpdateLocation delegate multiple times

Tags: swift, ios9, cllocationmanager

So there is the new  `requestLocation()` method on iOS9.   I am trying to use it to get only one location update but it hits the `didUpdateLocations` multiple times.

Isn't this suppose to call it only once ? i have set `distanceFilter` to 1000.0, so it is pretty broad to help return quickly.   Any ideas ?

even if i call the `stopUpdatingLocation()` inside the delegate method, i still get three hits of the delegate.

Note: same behavior occurs when i use `StartUpdatingLocation` instead,  i want only a single return as i want to obtain the user's current country, so feed the location to reversegeocoder

thanks in advance

Here is the code:

```
func getLocationOneTime(accuracy: Double){
    print("Acquiring location one time - accuracy requested:\(accuracy)")
    locationManager.distanceFilter = accuracy
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = accuracy
    // Start gpsOneTimeTimeout timer
    gpsTimeoutTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(gpsOneTimeTimeout, target: self, selector: #selector(self.reportTimeout), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    locationManager.requestLocation()
     }
```

Comment: where in the code are you calling this method?

Comment: @Jess updated code above

Comment: I'm seeing the same phenomenon. I regard it as a bug. It has something to do with caching (you can see that by looking at the timestamps on the locations you're getting).

Answer (score 4):

Usually for this kind of problem I just use an if statement to prevent the delegate function changing anything after the first call

in this case if you are just looking for the location I would do:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var userLocation: CLLocation!

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if userLocation == nil {
        if let location = locations.first {
            userLocation = location
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    } 
}
```

Edit: I had a look at the apple documentation for this and you are doing things right, I doubt you'll be able to prevent it through any reasonable means sadly.